# ubuntu 9.10 on an external usb drive: grub1 does not work

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot

I have installed Ubuntu on a partition of my external usb drive. Since I had problems with grub2, I have uninstalled it and installed grub1. But then the usb drive didn't boot anymore, and I am forced to the limited shell of grub1. If I write manually

```
kernel (hd0,4)/vmlinuz-2.6.31-15-generic root=/dev/sdb4 ro quiet splash
initrd (hd0,4)/boot/initrd.img-2.6.31-15-generic
boot
```

then Ubuntu is loaded,
but if I execute the commands

```
root (hd0,4)
setup (hd0)
```

as explained at http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-natively.html#Installing-GRUB-natively, next time I boot from usb I am forced again to the grub limited shell.
How can I restore a working grub?

Comment: ok, this looks like a problem with your Grub menu.  can you update this question with (a) your *menu.lst* file, (b) your *device.map* file, (c) where these files are located (what partition), and (d) what hard drives and partitions exist in your system?  i assume (hd0) is your USB drive and (hd0,4) is your root partition (/dev/sdb4); are there other drives on the system?